# Parse a DateTime value to sql in appropriate format ignoring the date MVC/C#

Tags: c#, sql, model-view-controller

I'm trying just to get Time value out of the model i want to parse to SQL, but it's automatically setting the time to 00:00. Where is the mistake?

```
if (DateTime.TryParseExact(s.EndTimeString, "HH:mm", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out parseEndTime))
{
    ModelState.AddModelError("EndTimeString", "End time is invalid");
}
s.EndTime = new DateTime(1900, 1, 1, parseEndTime.Hour, parseEndTime.Minute, 0);
```

Comment: Are you sure that `TryParseExact` returned `true`? Show a value of `EndTimeString`. Btw, you enter the `if` if it was a valid time but you are calling `AddModelError` with "End time is invalid"

Comment: Shouldn't it be if (DateTime.TryParseExact("19:45", "HH:mm", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out parseEndTime) == false)
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("EndTimeString", "End time is invalid");
            } . But other than that this example works for me if the passed value is sth. like "19:45". You should check the value inside s.EndTimeSTring.